# locking cells based on text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am really new to VBA and am trying to lock cells if a certain text is selected from a list via "Data Validation".
I keep getting an error "Run-time error '424': Object required.
I get an error on this code; 
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B7,b1000")) Is Nothing Then, 
what am I doing wrong here

```
Sub Locking2()
'
' Locking2 Macro
'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const csPASSWORD As String = "tndppp"
'--
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B7,b1000")) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub ' Do Nothing
End If

'--
''' 'B7:B1000' has been changed '''
' Unprotect sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect_
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=csPASSWORD
With Range("b8:b1000")
If UCase(Range("B7,b1000").Value) = "PP" Then
' Lock 'E7:N1000'
.Locked = True
Else
' Unlock 'E7:N1000'
.Locked = False
End If
End With
'--
'Protect sheet
ActiveSheet.Protect _
Password:=csPASSWORD, _
DrawingObjects:=True, _
Contents:=True, _
Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: you havent defined `target` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't defined `Target` in your `Locking2` function. You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B7:b1000")) Is Nothing Then
       Call Locking2(Target)
   End If
End Sub

Sub Locking2(ByVal Target As Range)
   Const csPASSWORD As String = "tndppp"

   ' Unprotect sheet
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=csPASSWORD
   ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
   With Range("E7:N1000")
      allPP = True
      For Each r In Range("B7:b1000")
          If UCase(r.Value) <> "PP" Then
              allPP = False
              Exit For
          End If
      Next
      If allPP Then
         ' Lock 'E7:N1000'
         .Locked = True
      Else
         ' Unlock 'E7:N1000'
         .Locked = False
      End If
  End With

 'Protect sheet
  ActiveSheet.Protect _
    Password:=csPASSWORD, _
    DrawingObjects:=True, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

This changes should fix an error

Comment: Should it be like this?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Sub Locking2(Target)
End Sub
Sub Locking2(ByVal Target As Range)

Const csPASSWORD As String = "tndppp"
'--
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B7,b1000")) Is Nothing Then

Exit Sub ' Do Nothing
End If

Comment: I just tried that and got an error. Compile error: Expected: identifier

Comment: In what line have you got it?

Comment: 2nd line. Call Sub Locking2(target). highlights SUB then prompts the error

Comment: Oh! It's my copy/paste error! change it to `Call Locking2(Target)` (without `Sub`). I've fixed it in my answer

Comment: its accepted finally but the code is still not working. Sorry I am beginner on this. I just dont understand what is wrong with it

Comment: Tell me please what are you going to check here `If UCase(Range("B7,b1000").Value) = "PP" Then`? Whether all values in range(b7:b1000) are equals "PP"?

Comment: Yes thats correct. If all ranges in (b7:b1000) equals "PP" then cells (E7:N100) need to lock. Have I done this all wrong? Was a copy and paster from another site and I just changed the ranges

Comment: I've updated my answer with new code. Hope it will works for you

Comment: P.S. in E7:N100 or in E7:N1000? my code locks E7:N1000, but you can easily change it

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way to not call locking2? I have changed the spreadsheet slightly. Can i just remove that or does it change everything?

Comment: Yes, you can move all code from `locking2` to `Private Sub Worksheet_Change`and put it inside `if` statement

Comment: also, it has protected the whole sheet. how do i stop that from happening?

Comment: its not done the range i specified, its protected the whole sheet

Comment: I've updated code: add `ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False` line